# Can not parse xml attributes in android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I have a xml like below, I tried to parse it with `XmlPullParser` in android by below code, every thing is right the only problem is I can not parse the `url` tag attributes, it returns null, what is the problem?

XML:

```
<doc>
 <urls>
  <url isIR="false" bitrate="320" extension="MP3" size="9.9MB">
  http://example.mp3
  </url>
 </urls>
 <caption>
  <![CDATA[ don t bother ]]>
 </caption>
 <artist>
  <![CDATA[ shakira ]]>
 <artist>
 <album>
  <![CDATA[ star mark greatest hits (cd) ]]>
 <album>
</doc>
```

Code:

```
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                    ava = new Ava2();
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = parser.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                    avaList.add(ava);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                    ava.setUrl(text);
                    ava.setBitrate(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "bitrate"));
                    ava.setSize(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "size"));
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("caption")) {
                    ava.setCaption(text);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
                    ava.setArtist(text);
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("album")) {
                    ava.setAlbum(text);
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }
```

Comment: use `SAXParser`...it will be more easier.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/

Comment: do you have any idea how to fix it with XmlPullParser?

Comment: sorry, I didn't use `XmlPullParser` ever. So I can't help you with this. But, when I was studying about XML parsing then I found SAXParser is better. That's I suggested you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
           else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                ava.setUrl(text);
                for(int i =0 i < parser.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                   if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equals("bitrate")){
                       ava.setBitrate(parser.getAttributeValue(i));
                   }else if(parser.getAttributeName(i).equals("size")){
                       ava.setSize(parser.getAttributeValue(i));
                   }
                }
            }
```

**EDIT:**

```
        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                ava = new Ava2();
            }
            if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
                avaList.add(ava);
            } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("url")) {
                ava.setUrl(text);
                ava.setBitrate(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "bitrate"));
                ava.setSize(parser.getAttributeValue(null, "size"));
            } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("caption")) {
                ava.setCaption(text);
            } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("artist")) {
                ava.setArtist(text);
            } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("album")) {
                ava.setAlbum(text);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: it is still returning null

Comment: getAttributeCount() returns `-1`

Comment: @user3326853 check my edit do that all inside your `XmlPullParser.START_TAG`

Comment: @user3326853 Because `</url>` is the `END_TAG` there is no Attribute so that null returns.

Comment: @user3326853 did you try caption,artist and album in `END_TAG`

Comment: I put size and bitrate on start tag and other is end tag, now it works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to first parse "urls" tag and then "url" tag.

Comment: I can read the site url without parsein `urls`, the only problem is with the attributes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parser.getAttributeName() and parser.getAttributeValue() functions.

When the case is START_TAG you can get a count of tags using parser.getAttributeCount() and then use a for loop from 0 to count -1 and pass the loop integer to getAttributeName and getAttributeValue funcitons.

```
int count=parser.getAttributeCount();
if(count!= -1) {


    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {

        String name = parser.getAttributeName(i);
        String value = parser.getAttributeValue(i);
    }
}
```